# what is azure Power BI Embedded resource?

Tags: azure, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

In azure, I can create a power BI embedded resource, what is the relationship between this and the reports we have on powerbi.com?

Are they somehow linked or they are totally independent things?

I was told that this power BI embedded resource can be used to create reports and embed into my apps. Is there a way to upload a pbix file to this power BI embedded resource? From azure portal, I can't find an upload report function.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This resource is a dedicated capacity to which you can assign workspaces from PowerBI.com
Here is the Power BI embedded FAQ: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded-faq

Comment: Hi, I know that document, but I am not sure it said anything  useful. Microsoft has a migration tool to move old azure workspace collections to powerbi embedded. However, that tool copies reports to powerbi.com, other than the azure embedded resources.  They have other examples showing how to embed reports in your own app, however, the requirements there is to have a azure active directory app, a workspace in powerbi.com and seems no need of this "azure embedded resources". That is why I don't really know what is the purpose of this azure resource, which is quite expensive as well.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Power BI Embedded resource is a dedicated capacity needed for your embeded reports to run in production. You can purchase it on Azure and assign it to your workspaces in Power BI Service (PowerBI.com) as a Dedicated Capacity.

It is pratically the same as purchasing Power BI Premium, but it is purchased from Azure rather than from Office Portal and aimed to ISVs rather than corporate customers, as told by Adam Saxton in his session ["Microsoft Power BI: Embedding analytics in your apps and portals"](https://myignite.techcommunity.microsoft.com/sessions/65441) on Microsoft Ignite 2018 - this session is a great resource on Power BI Embedded.

As your mentioned in your [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52390103/what-is-azure-power-bi-embedded-resource#comment91744409_52395316), **the need** to purchase Azure Power BI Embedded is to generate tokens in production enviroment, since generating this tokens with a PRO license is limited to development testing (capped) as seen in the FAQ Eli mentioned earlier:

> #### [How many embed tokens can I create?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded-faq#how-many-embed-tokens-can-i-create)
>
> Embed tokens with PRO license are intended for development testing, so the number of embed tokens a Power BI master account can generate is limited. You must purchase a
> capacity for embedding in a production environment. There is no limit to how many embed tokens you can generate when a capacity is purchased. Go to Available Features to check the usage value that indicates the current embedded usage in percentage.